# Why does MongoID generate different values?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have a a relational database with a user table and has user id's etc. However the commenting system is stored in Mongo and

```
$author = new Author();
$userID = 1;
$author->setId( new \MongoId( $userID ) ); <--- different ID generated everytime

$discussion = new Discussion();
             $discussion->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
             $discussion->setAuthor($author);
```

The ID that is generated is different every time so I have values like 5082a694253b4a1201000000, 5082a55e253b4a1f05000000.

How do I relate back to the user ID for example user ID 1? Or should just forget the whole new MongoID business and just store the user ID in the document?

Comment: It is because `MongoId` is designed to generate those strings, if you don't put in a `ObjectId` it will try and create a new one. Also instead of `datetime` use `MongoDate`, that will convert properly to the mongodb standard.

Comment: I followed the documentation on http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/introduction.html . Thoughts?

Comment: fascinating didn't know their `datetime` did actually link correctly to `mongodate` but if they say it does it must, I have looked around and it seems to work

Comment: cool thanks for checking it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoid.construct.php):

> public MongoId::__construct ([ string $id = NULL ] )
>
> $id:
>   A string to use as the id. Must be 24 hexidecimal characters. If an invalid string is passed to this constructor, the constructor will ignore it and create a new id value.

So that's why, even if you give an id to the MongoId, it doesn't fit into a **24 hexidecimal characters**. So MongoId ignore it and generate a new one.

I think you just need to define the UserId as it is:

```
$author = new Author();
$author->setUserId($userID);
```